# How to mock imported commonJS module in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I am writing a test for a class that `import` a commonJS style module in Jest.
The commonJS format module I am importing is an external library for external connection, and I want to Mock it with Jest, but I cannot.
Please give me some advice.
(If I can't, I would appreciate it if you could tell me that I can't.)

External library I want to Mock (ganblib.js)

```js
module.exports = class GanbLib {

    constructor({clientID, clientSecret, nonceCallbacks}) {
        // code
    }

    async refreshTokens(refreshToken, tryCounter = 0) {
        // code
    }
```

Tested class

```js
import express from 'express'
import GanbLib from './ganblib.js'

const controller = express.Router()

controller.post('/api/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
  const clientOptions = {
    clientID: 'client_id',
    clientSecret: 'secrete_id',
    nonceCallbacks: [()=>{}, ()=>{}],
  }
  const ganbLib = new GanbLib(clientOptions)

  ganbLib
    .refreshTokens('refresh_token')
    .then((res) => {
      // code
    })
```

Test class

```js
import request from 'supertest'

describe('POST /api/endpoint', () => {
  const endpoint = '/api/endpoint'

  test('refresh token', async () => {
    const mockRefreshTokens = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      access_token: 'token',
      refresh_token: null,
    })
    jest.mock('./ganblib.js', () => {
      return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return { refreshTokens: mockRefreshTokens }
      })
    })

    await request(app).post(endpoint).expect(200)
  })
})
```

I tried the above, but the `refreshTokens` did not become Mock.
However, if I wrote `const GanbLib = require('./ganblib.js')` instead of `import GanbLib from './ganblib.js'`, I was able to Mock as expected.

Is there any way to make it Mock with `import` instead of `require`?

Note that `.babelrc` has already been configured as follows to handle ES Modules in Jest.

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `jest.mock()` to module scope and [replace the mock using `mockImplementation()` or `mockImplementationOnce()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce)

> You can replace all of the above mocks in order to change the implementation, for a single test or all tests, by calling mockImplementation() on the existing mock.

E.g.

`ganblib.js`:

```js
module.exports = class GanbLib {
  constructor({ clientID, clientSecret, nonceCallbacks }) {
    // code
  }

  async refreshTokens(refreshToken, tryCounter = 0) {
    // code
    return {
      access_token: 'real token',
      refresh_token: null,
    }
  }
}
```

`app.js`:

```js
import express from 'express'
import GanbLib from './ganblib'

const app = express();
const controller = express.Router()

controller.post('/api/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
  const clientOptions = {
    clientID: 'client_id',
    clientSecret: 'secrete_id',
    nonceCallbacks: [() => { }, () => { }],
  }
  const ganbLib = new GanbLib(clientOptions)

  ganbLib
    .refreshTokens('refresh_token')
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result)
    })
})

app.use(controller)

export { app }
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
import request from 'supertest'
import { app } from './app';
import GanbLib from './ganblib'

jest.mock('./ganblib');

describe('POST /api/endpoint', () => {
  const endpoint = '/api/endpoint'

  test('refresh token', async () => {
    const mockRefreshTokens = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      access_token: 'fake token',
      refresh_token: null,
    });
    GanbLib.mockImplementation(() => {
      return { refreshTokens: mockRefreshTokens }
    })

    const res = await request(app).post(endpoint)
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
    expect(res.body).toEqual({
      access_token: 'fake token',
      refresh_token: null,
    })
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75878294/app.test.js (14.922 s)
  POST /api/endpoint
    ✓ refresh token (53 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   92.86 |        0 |   42.86 |   92.31 |                   
 app.js     |     100 |      100 |      60 |     100 |                   
 ganblib.js |      50 |        0 |       0 |      50 | 8                 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.235 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```